# Difference between invocation variable set using Message Properties transformer and set-variable transformer?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Context for the question is that: When I use set-variable, then the datamapper recognizes and shows the variable in drop-down but it never shows up when invocation variable is set using Message Properties transformer.
Is this normal?

Comment: Note that DataMapper is an Enterprise Edition feature so you should be able to get MuleSoft's professional support on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message Properties Transformer is the old way of adding variables/properties of different scope to message.

Mule refined the message-properties-transformer and split that into `<set-variable>`, `<set-property>` and `<set-session-variable>` transformers.
Apart from the clear seperation of functionality, this makes the flow more readable and understandable when looking at a flow diagram.

Point to remember is, Message Properties by default adds the property to outbound scope. If you want to add it to invocation scope that have to be mentioned in the scope attribute.

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="invocation">
    <add-message-property key="someKey" value="someValue"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see this behavior after setting the scope to "invocation" itself. Another observation is, if I create a invocation variable inside a groovy script datamapper doesn't recognize. It seems only set-variable is visible to datamappers.

Comment: @RyanHoegg Thanks for the observation. I edited it properly now. :)

Answer (score 1):

No it is not normal.

Make sure to use the `invocation` scope on the message properties transformer.

Comment: I did David. Also If any invocation variable is set inside a Groovy script, that variable doesn't show up in the datamapper dropdown. Only variables that are set from set-variable do show up. Here I am only concerned about invocation variables. I didn't experiment with other variables.

Comment: Feels like a bug then: open a JIRA at https://www.mulesoft.org/jira And as user1760178 said, the `message-properties-transformer` is old stuff, you should be using `set-variable` anyways.

Comment: I think the Data Mapper feature you're looking for is called Data Sense, and I don't think it will be able to get the metadata it needs from a groovy script.  It should be possible to add it to message properties transformer though.

Comment: Why not? One can set message properties from a Groovy script. These properties should be visible to Data Mapper.